# How to navigate through the hierarchy of SQL Server 2012 LocalDB objects using the PowerShell SQLPS module?

Tags: powershell, localdb

From a program developer’s perspective, combining PowerShell with “Microsoft SQL Server 2012 LocalDB” to interact with the SQL Server Database Engine is very appealing. Connecting to LocalDB instances from PowerShell, working with database objects and executing Transact-SQL statements works just fine. This also holds true when adding the “Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Shared Management Objects” (SMO) to this mix.

What I cannot get to work is navigating through LocalDB instances by means of the PowerShell SQLPS module (“ Microsoft Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack”). The latter tries obtaining SQL Server Service information whereas LocalDB does not create any database services.

Would there, nevertheless, be  a way to make LocalDB instances visible to the SQLPS module?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to extend SQLPS and/or SMO to include LocalDB instances on the list of SQL Server instances. Currently SQLPS and SMO don't understand LocalDB instance model, just like (I think) it didn't understand User Instances of SQL Server Express before. Also mixing regular and LocalDB instances could be confusing to end users. LocalDB instances are per-user and only visible by the user who owns them, so different users would get a different list on the same machine. Regular SQL Server instances are installed per-machine, and all users see the same list.

I bet you could write your own PowerShell plugin or module. All you need to do is to call [LocalDBGetInstances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh234622.aspx) and [LocalDBGetInstanceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245734.aspx) functions from LocaLDB API (available through C/C++) plus the existing SQLPS or SMO for the regular SQL Server instances. I'm not sure how you distribute such plugin though.

Comment: … or write a PowerShell module, which is indeed what I did for the purpose of navigating conveniently through LocalDB instances and, thus, largely duplicating functionality that the SQLPS module provides anyway. No problem to connect from PowerShell to LocalDB instances with SqlConnection or alternatively SMO or a combination of both.

What I do not know is how to get the SQLPS module to not just see the SQL Server Express Instances of the local machine but also the LocalDB instances.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood your question, missing the SQLPS part. I don't think it is possible to extend the SQLPS or SMO it wraps in the way you want it. Keep in mind that LocalDB instances belong to the user and are only visible to the user who owns them, so I'm not sure if having them listed among regular SQL Server instances would be a good idea in general case. We would see a different list depending on who the caller is...